# Delete unpushed Git commit in netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, commit

I need to remove my last unpushed commit in netbeans IDE.

I commit my code. But found unpulled commit on master. Now I have to revert my committed modification.

Comment: Do you want to destroy your changed or try to apply them on top of the pull changes (without a merge)?

Comment: I want destroy the committed changes

Comment: I've update my response with a correction and to only show the deletion

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
git revert --hard HEAD^
```

will roll back one commit. The will delete the commit and destroy the changes from that commit. Use HEAD~2 for two commits, or replace the number with any other.